# How do I create a struct that is globaly accessible in Swift?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller

My idea is to create a class "cart" which includes a class "order", which again include a struct "orderHeader" and an array of struct "orderItems"

From different VC's I need to be able to update any items in the cart or information in the order header. Where should I instantiate the cart class and it's vars for it to be available across all VC's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a struct to store all the global variables and other datas

```
Class CommonData{
        public static var liveCart:Cart? //anything do you want to store globally in app
        public static var loginUser:User?
}
```

then you can modify or get data from anywhere in your application

```
CommonData.cart?.setTotal(total:100.00) //add data to the cart using mutable functions
CommonData.cart?.total //get data from cart
```

this is sample struct for **Cart**

```
struct Cart{
     let id:Int
     .
     .
     .
     var subTotal:Double
     var total:Double

        //this is the mutable function. this is similar to encapsulation setter in OOP
        mutating func setTotal(total:Double){
             self.total = total
        }
    }
```